# A few question about PHP memcache

Tags: php, memcached

**1)**
I understand I can call this

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);
```

in the header files of my site with no impact on pages that don't use memcache
but what about this

```
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
```

Should this be called on a page to page basis?

---

**2)**
what if the server does not have enough memory to write new caches and memcache tries to store a cache?

---

**3)**
I know keys can have up to a 30 day lifespan,
Is there a way to flush all keys out of memory, especially useful for testing phase?

**4)**
Also this code, the first variable is connecting, so for example if I have 5 sections on a page that add/update/delete from memcache, do I need to run this connection everytime, or is it possible to connect 1 time and do everything per page load?

```
memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'var_key', 'some variable', 0, 30)
```

**5)** 
Is there a function or anything to show like how much memory is available and being used on a php page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. yes, no network calls are made until an attempt to fetch, delete, etc..., so it does not hurt to allocate the object in case it is needed. (EDIT: I was thinking of the "memcached" extension here, turns out the "memcache" extension does in fact open a connection to the memcache server, though the hit is negligable at most)
2. memcache will drop least used items to attempt to make space for the new object
3. $memcache_obj->flush();
4. connect only needs to happen once per script run, easiest to place the connect at the top of your page or in a class constructer
5. $memcache_obj->getStats() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-getstats.php

Comment: awsome thanks, you are the memcache guy I have seen many of  your post on the issue. Also i added 1 more question above if you care to look

Answer (score 3):

Jason answered your questions very well but I thought that I would add some notes:

2) Note that if you try to store more than 1MB (default) into a key the memcache extension will return a FALSE value. It will also return FALSE if it can't write a key for any reason.

3) Keys *can* have a >30 day lifespan (TTL). Just add the TTL to the current time and use that as the TTL. Using your example call, it might be something like this (coded for clarity):

```
$ttl = 60*60*24*60; // 60 days
$newTTL = time()+$ttl;
memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'cache_key', 'some data', 0, $newTTL)
```

5) If you are talking about PHP memory then `memory_get_usage()` will get you what you want. Memcache memory is a little harder to come by but using the `getStats()` call will start you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-connect.php suggests that memcache_connect() is the same as instantiating a Memcache and calling connect() on it
2. http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_memcached%27s_cache? says "If the server is out of memory, expired slabs are replaced first, then the oldest unused slabs go next."
3. Restart the memcached instance, or call [flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-flush.php), which will invalidate all cache items on the server